# Having an issue with PHP styling

Tags: php, mysql

so basically what I'm trying to do is allow users to change their details which most of it works, so lets get down to the problem. If a user changes their password and it is successful in the validation it will change their password and a message will appear saying 'Password has been changed'. So this is my issue, if I change or make a mistake on purpose it shows the 'Home Button' on all the validation. So lets say a user changed their password 'Password has been changed' and there is a 'Home' button underneath it and lets say the email change had failed 'Your email has not been changed' aswel with a 'Home' button. So what I'm trying to do basically is to have 1 home button for all the fields without have to do `<a href='index.php'`(home)

Examples

http://puu.sh/cm3JK/84b14648c3.jpg ( I need a button on this page so for every validation)

http://puu.sh/cm3S8/3b60406c18.jpg (If I put 'home' here and lets say I change the current email and password it will repeat 'home' twice)

```
<title>Honda | </title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Julius+Sans+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />



<?php
session_start();



$username = $_SESSION['sess_user'];

    echo '<div class="search1"><h2>'.$username.'</h2></div>';


    if (isset($_SESSION['sess_user']))
    {
        //user is logged in

        if (isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
            //start changing password
            //check fields

            $oldpassword = md5($_POST['oldpassword']);
            $newpassword = md5($_POST['newpassword']);
            $email = $_POST['email'];


            $repeatnewpassword = md5($_POST['repeatnewpassword']);


            //check password against db
            include('../includes/config.php');

            $queryget = mysql_query("SELECT password FROM login WHERE username='$username'") or die ("change password failed");
            $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryget);
            $oldpassworddb = $row['password'];

            //check passwords
            if ($oldpassword==$oldpassworddb)
            {

                if (isset($_POST['repeatnewpassword']) AND isset($_POST['newpassword']) AND $_POST['newpassword'] != '') {
                    if ($newpassword==$repeatnewpassword)
                    {
                        $querychange = mysql_query("UPDATE login SET password='$newpassword' WHERE   username='$username'");
                        echo "<div class='successmate'><br><br><br><br><hr>Password has been changed</hr></div><div class='successmate'><br><hr><br><h2><p><a href='index2.php'><br><br></a></p></h2></div>";
                    }
                    else {echo "<div class='results'>new password(s) dont match</div><div class='successmate'><br><br><h2><p><a href='changepassword.php'>try again?</a></p></h2></div>";}

                }


            }
            else {echo "<div class='results'>current password doesnt match</div><div class='successmate'><h2><p><a href='changepassword.php'><br><br>Try again?</a></p></h2></div>";}


            if (isset($_POST['email']) AND $_POST['email'] != '') {
                $querychange = mysql_query("UPDATE login SET email='$email' WHERE   username='$username'");
                echo "<div class='successmate'><br><br><br><br><hr>Your email has been changed</hr></div><div class='successmate'><br><hr><br><h2><p><a href='index2.php'><br><br>Home</a></p></h2></div>";
            }}


        else
        {

            echo"
        <form class='search1' action='changepassword.php' method='POST'>
        <label>Current Password:</label> <input type='password' id='password' name='oldpassword'><p>
        <label>New Password:</label> <input type='password' id='password' name='newpassword'><p>
        <label>Repeat New Password:</label> <input type='password'  name='repeatnewpassword'><p>
        <label>Email:</label> <input type='email'  name='email'><p>
        <input type='submit' name='submit' class='submit' value='submit'><br><br><br>
        <h2><p><a href='index2.php'>Back</a></p></h2>
        </form>
        ";


        }}
    else
        die ("You must be logged in to change your password");


    ?>

<img src="../images/main.jpg">
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm still checking but the problem could be in the CSS class you are using in the tags echoed in the php code. Check it out.